# calloc() syntax declaration with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int *ptr,a[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i;    
    ptr=(int*)calloc(a[6]*sizeof(int),2);
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d",*ptr+a[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);
    getch();
}
```

the program works perfectly!!
but my questions

1. Does the declaration of a[6] inside calloc() correct. since the syntax for calloc is `ptr_var=(cast_type *)calloc(no_of_blocks,size_of_each_block);`.what does the `calloc()` and a[6] do now.
2. What does *ptr takes value because ptr doesnt get assigned any address.
3. In printf does *ptr needs there.then what does it do.

Comment: This is pretty meaningless; there is no `a[6]`, and you're supply the size as part of the wrong argument to `calloc`.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845)

Comment: "the program works perfectly" - are you *sure* about that? Your code invokes *undefined behavior* in the first `calloc` invoke by dereferencing an array one-element-past its last addressable element. Your program is ill-formed. If it "works", it isn't perfectly, its by sheer luck (all of it bad).

Comment: ive tried without a cast.it works on turbo c. the link ishttp://www.vdesignourweb.com/c/c_dynamic_memory.html

Comment: http://www.vdesignourweb.com/c/c_dynamic_memory.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.does the declaration of a[6] inside calloc() correct. since the syntax for calloc is
```

No, its not correct. The array `a` has 6 elements with indices 0,1,2,3,4,5. but no 6.

```
2.what does *ptr takes value because ptr doesnt get assigned any address.
```

ptr does get an address. You are assigning address to ptr when you make the call to calloc() and store the returning address to it. As *ptr is a pointer to an int, it will take integer as a value.

```
3.in printf does *ptr needs there.then what does it do.
```

Since you have not stored any value in that allocated memory that ptr points to, it will be all 0's

Comment: @haris@chuxok now a[6] should not present inside calloc(). right!

Comment: according to your code `a[0] = 1, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 3, a[3] = 4, a[4] = 5, a[5] = 6` now you choose what should be inside calloc()

Comment: no my doubt is whether a[6] will impact calloc() or not withot it.

Comment: a[6] must present or not

Comment: @hariswe will keep it as a[5] itself.again my question is array present inside calloc() is right or not

Answer (score 3):

1. `ptr=(int*)calloc(a[6]*sizeof(int),2);` is amiss.
   The `(int*)` cast is not needed.
   The `a[6]` is the *value* of `a[6]` which is outside `a` valid index range of `0 ...5`.
   Instead the number of elements and the size of size of `*ptr` are needed.
   `calloc()` will zero-fill the memory assigned to `ptr`.

   ```
   size_t n = TBD;  // Somehow determine the desired number of `int`s for `ptr`.
   ptr = calloc(n, sizeof *ptr);
   ```
2. `ptr` does get a value.  To see its value

   ```
   printf("%p\n", (void*) ptr);
   ```
3. To print the values of the elements of `ptr`:

   ```
   size_t n =  TBD;  // n is the number of elements.
   for (size_t i=0; i<n; n++) 
     printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
   ```

`a` does not need memory allocation as that was done in its declaration.  To see its values

```
    for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof a/sizeof a[0]; i++) 
      printf("%d\n", a[i]);
```